# Matlab: variable legend in plot

Tags: matlab, legend

I have a figure in which I plot a variable number of points (resembling nodes of a network) and three trajectories. When I call `legend` I get the `o` symbol (corresponding to the nodes) also for the trajectories.

I know this is because the `legend` function needs a string for every label I need, but since I can't know the total number of nodes "a priori" (because it's a user-defined parameter), is there a way of specifying that only the nodes are labeled as `o` while being able to label the trajectories normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell `legend` exactly what you want.

the trajectories:

```
t(1) = plot( xvector1, yvector1, linspecs ...)
t(2) = plot( xvector2, yvector2, ...)
...
t(n) = plot( xvectorn, yvectorn, ...)
```

and their labels:

```
tLabel{1} = 'trajectory label #1'
...
tLabel{n} = 'trajectory label #n'
```

the same for the nodes:

```
p(1) = plot( x1, y1, 'o',...)
p(2) = plot( x2, y2, 'o',...)
...
p(m) = plot( xm, ym, 'o',...)

pLabel{1} = 'node label #1'
...
pLabel{m} = 'node label #m'
```

finally plot the legend:

```
lh = legend( [traj(1:n),p(1:m)] , tLabel{1:n}, pLabel{1:m} );
```

Of course if all nodes have the same names and style, just use the first entry of the node-array:

```
lh = legend( [traj(1:n),p(1)] , tLabel{1:n}, pLabel{1} );
```

Comment: great! I have a question, though, wouldn't this result in a very big legend box in the case the user works with, e.g., 10 nodes? Isn't that information redundant?

Comment: of course, have a look at my edit. If all nodes look the same, just print the first entry into the legend.